# Conditional format Excel multiple adjacent cells in range

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have an Excel spreadsheet where data in is in the range B4:K12.  Each row has 5 sections (2 columns each).

I need to format B4 and C4 identically based on if C4 = "D".  Then D4 & E4 if E4="D" etc throughout the range.

I have not been able to get anything to work here.  How should this be done?

Thanks,
t2t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula:

`=OFFSET($B4,0,((INT((COLUMN(B4)/2)-1)*2)+1),1,1)="D"`

Does that do what you want ?

Basically this is what it's doing:

`OFFSET($B4,....)`  is taking the first column of each row as it's reference point.
We then just need to figure out which column we need to look at.

`COLUMN(B4)`  - take the column # of the cell in question.

`((INT((COLUMN(B4)/2)-1)*2+1)` is just doing adjustments to the column number to turn it into an offset.

Try running just this part of the formula in a cell on row 20 .. build it up and you'll see it convering :`2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ....` into `1,1,3,3,5, ...` etc.

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you so much @Ditto